# How can I find papers that are not sponsored by industry?

Tags: funding, industry, databases, publication-bias

Are there any databases or search filters for published peer-reviewed articles, particularly concerning environmental issues, that are neither affiliated with nor funded by corporate interests?

I am trying to find peer-reviewed articles on the history and impact of plastics pollution. Most articles I have found either have authors affiliated with petroleum/packaging/fast-moving consumer good companies, were commissioned by those companies, or received funding influenced by those companies.

I am not asking whether industry-sponsored papers are less accurate, as [this has been asked before](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/128498/452). I understand that high-quality independent research can emerge from (and be enabled by) corporate funds, and that every funding source has biases of some kind.

I would just like to know how to find articles whose authors and funding have no corporate ties.

Additionally, I understand that not all connections with industry are apparent. As an example, one article encouraging plastics packaging had no author affiliations but received funding from a major English research council. Although this council describes itself as independent, its directors' declarations of interest contain many corporate ties, including to petroleum giants. Since this is indirect, I would not expect it to qualify as "industry-sponsored."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have access to Web of Science, there is an option to sort by funding agencies. Clicking the "more options" link also allows you to exclude funding agencies. It's not perfect since the last time I used it there were quite a lot of false positives & negatives, but it's better than nothing.

[image]